# Two WebView Change Split Orientation Without Reload View

Tags: android, layout, webview, split, orientation

I have two WebView, when potrait, it's positioned at above and bottom, but when landscape, split it to left and right.

I've successfully create it with change the orientation view in `onCreateView` and keeping the state,but it reload the webview and a loading pop up shown blocking the apps. I think someone know how to change the split orientation without reloading the apps?

Current Method:

```
    View v = null;
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_potrait, container, false);
    } else {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_landscape, container, false);
    }
```

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/parent_view"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                xmlns:spl="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="@color/light_gray"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <SplitPaneLayout
            android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            spl:splitterPosition="43%"
            spl:orientation="vertical"
            spl:splitterBackground="@drawable/splitter_bg_h"
            spl:splitterDraggingBackground="#F0F0F0"
            >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview1"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "0dp"
                android:text = "YOUR FIRST TEXT"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                android:autoLink="web|all"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                />
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webview2"
                android:layout_width = "fill_parent"
                android:layout_height = "0dp"
                android:text = "YOUR SECOND TEXT"
                android:autoLink="web|all"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight = "1"
                />
        </SplitPaneLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I use this split pane:
https://github.com/MobiDevelop/android-split-pane-layout

Answer (score 0):

at runtime android should choose the portrait/landscape layout.

by declaring:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

`onCreate`, `onPause` and `onDestroy` are not called but instead `onConfigurationChanged` is called. You can handle everything you want to do programmatically in this method!

for more information see [Handling Configuration Changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#HandlingTheChange)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question which is: *how to **change the split orientation** without reloading the apps?*